# Blazor EditForm

Tags: blazor, blazor-editform

Need help on:

How to use the EditForm, how to validate the fields, and how to post the form data to a Web Api, to save it in a database.

I know if I just use "form" I can have validation types for phone ("tel") and email ("email"). With EditForm is there equivalent validators, if not, can you give me an example"? Do I need the have a function inside my @code that does this (via button click) and then if validation is OK calls the async proc InvokeGetQuote?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Validators/Validating**
Your model is the beginning of this work. Let us use a person:

```
public class Person
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(10)]
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
```

Above this DisplayName, there are some annotation. google it, see some examples, add error messages to them.

On the client side add components to work with this and validate. They are standard components and very easy to work with.

**How to display this?**
Well, thats the easy part. First you retrive a person objekt from your backend, if database read about Entity Framework.

When you are at the webpage, the code will look something like this.

```
<input value="@context.DisplayName" />
```

The code above is "not even close to correct", but you see the point. I preferr to use MatBlazor or Bootstrap. If you databind DisplayName to the component, saving to the database is very easy, since it is databound, and validated by the model, simply do a SaveChanges on DBContext.

**Note:**
It was hard to understand your question and what you actually were looking for. I answered in hope to get you started. I recommend you to ask just one question pr post.
Like: Question about annotations or Good tutorials on blazor serverside?

Comment: Sorry, I got help on a previous question were I needed help, I asked him about the form validation and he asked to post a new question. So my terrible question was out of context.  I have a form and I am using EditForm, I need to validate an email and a phone number. If I were using just "Form" then I'd have fields of type phone and email but I can't find the same with EditForm, If somebody has a suggestion I'd appreciate, my comment at the end was that "onsubmit" connect an event that will try and perfom these validations with C#.